# How to save JSON response of HTTP GET in a .json file in C++?

Tags: c++, json, boost-asio

I have written following program to GET a JSON response from the server. The code is correct and the response from the server is as per my expectation.

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>  //I have not shown some header for sake of readability

int main ()
{

        try
        {   
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s;
            s.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
            const std::string IP = "123.456.789.000";
            s.connect(IP, "83");

            if (!s) {
                std::cout << "Unable to connect: " << s.error().message() << "\n";
            }

            s << "GET /MY_PATH HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            s << "Host: 123.456.789.000:83\r\n";
            s << "Accept: */*\r\n";
            s << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

            // Checking if response is OK.
            std::string http_version;
            s >> http_version;
            unsigned int status_code;
            s >> status_code;
            std::cout<<"\nHTTP " << status_code << std::endl;

            std::string status_message;
            std::getline(s, status_message);

            if (!s || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/") {
                std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
            }

            if (status_code != 200) {
                std::cout << "\nResponse returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
            }

            // Processing the response headers, which were terminated by a blank line.
            std::string header;

            while (std::getline(s, header) && header != "\r")
            std::cout << header << "\n";

            std::cout << "\n";

            // Writing the remaining data to output.
            std::cout << s.rdbuf() << "\n" << std::endl;

         }// try ends here

         catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
         }

}
```

Response from the server is as follows:

```
HTTP 200
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft
X-AspNet-Version: 4
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 07:49:57 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 345

[{"CmdID":"30b2b2ca-376d-42bf-a931-1b92679871fc","EID":"102","CID":"00000102","NAME":"ABCD","BDAY":null,"VDATE":null,"UID":null,"ImgFileType":null,"EIMAGEBASE64STR":null},{"CmdID":"83c7d70da361-4f98-9803-1d5b7771d329","EID":"00000109","CID":"00000109","NAME":"CDEF","BDAY":null,"VDATE":null,"UID":null,"ImgFileType":null,"EIMAGEBASE64STR":null}]
```

Now I wish to save the JSON response string into a **.json** file. How could I do this ?

At this moment I can store the complete server response which includes the HEADER and JSON string. But I am interested in JSON string only.

In the next steps (which I have already done) this json string will be parsed and store into sqlite3 database. But unfortunately I am stuck at this.

Kindly help. Thank you

Comment: `// Writing the remaining data to output.
            std::cout << s.rdbuf() << "\n" << std::endl;` just write to file. What's the problem?

Comment: ohhh...Yes !!!! Now I am embarassed to post this question :(

Comment: Isn't the problem skipping the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually this was a cake walk. I apologise to waste your time.

To get just the JSON string output in the file I did the following.

```
        // Writing the remaining data to output.
        freopen("JSONoutput.json","w",stdout);    
        std::cout << s.rdbuf() << "\n" << std::endl;
```

*freopen() : Reuses stream to either open the file specified by filename or to change its access mode.If a new filename is specified, the function first attempts to close any file already associated with stream (third parameter) and disassociates it. Then, independently of whether that stream was successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file specified by filename and associates it with the stream just as fopen would do using the specified mode.*

This creates a file **JSONoutput.json** and the only the JSON string gets stored into it and nothing else.